# Any freeware/ideas for getting Windows 2008's backups to dump to tape after backing up to disk?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server that is being backed up to an external ISCSI drive nightly.

The problem is, we'd like to use our Tape Drive (VXA 320) that Windows sees just fine to take those backups in the "WindowsImageBackup" folder and dump them to tape once a month so that we can at least have something offsite.

I really don't want to go through the hassle of licensing BackupExec or similar if possible.

All I'm really after is some kind of copy utility that can copy the "WindowsImageBackup" folder over to the tape drive.

Ideas?

P.S.  If by doing this it wouldn't matter for a restore regardless, then let me know, but I would assume I could copy the folder back over to the server and then have Windows Backup find it again.

Comment: Doesn't Server 2008 still have Windows Backup? If it does why not use that?

Comment: @John - Server 2008 no longer supports backup to tape using the built-in utility.  That's the reason for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old "Services for Unix" (aka Interix) had a `tar` command that would work with tape drives. Cygwin `tar` should be able to access the tape drive, too.

Answer (score 0):

[Amanda](http://www.amanda.org/) has a free version